# Can't access prevState with useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-state

I have a component where I'm attempting to capture the previousState of something but no matter what it keeps returning the initial value. This is leading me to believe that there's re-rendering that's happening so it keeps defaulting to the initial state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { InfoWindow } from "../info-window/info-window";
import { LocationProps } from "../../../interfaces/location-inteface";

export interface Props {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
    location: LocationProps;
}

type PreviousLocation = {
    isActive: boolean;
    location: Props["location"];
};

export const InStoreMarker: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const { location } = props;
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
    const [infoWindowVisible, setActiveInfoWindowVisible] = useState(false);
    const [activeLocation, setActiveLocation] = useState({
        isActive: false,
        location: null
    });
    const [previousLocation, setPreviousLocation] = useState(null);


    const onClick = (location: LocationProps, prevLocation: PreviousLocation) => {
        setIsActive(true);
        setActiveInfoWindowVisible(true);
        setPreviousLocation(prevLocation);
        setActiveLocation({
            isActive: true,
            location: location,
        });
        console.log("Click previousLocation", previousLocation);
        console.log("Click location", location);
    };

    const onClose = (value: boolean) => {
        setIsActive(value);
        setActiveInfoWindowVisible(value);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("activeLocation", activeLocation);
        console.log("previousLocation", previousLocation);
    }, [previousLocation, activeLocation]);

    return (
        <div className={styles.inStoreMarkerContainer}>
            {isActive && infoWindowVisible && (
                <InfoWindow
                    location={location}
                    onClose={onClose}
                />
            )}
            <div
                className={styles.inStoreMarker}
                onClick={() => onClick(location, activeLocation)}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The console log inside of the `setActiveLocation` callback keeps returning

```
{
    id: null,
    isActive: false,
    location: null
}
```

I tried creating a `usePrevious` function as shown at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state but that would always return `undefined` so I'm a little stuck right now.

Comment: Have you tried not to make that a `const`?

Comment: @JacoboTapia like making `previousLocation` a `let` and just assign the value? Yes. Regardless of that, `prevState` seems to always be the `activeLocation` initial state so that's what's currently being assigned.

Comment: @JacoboTapia ok i've switched things around a bit and after stepping through the debugger it seems like `activeLocation` always defaults back to it's initial state which I can't figure out why it's doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a custom hook can help you?

Maybe  [usePrevious](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)  could solve this without adding boilerplate to you actual component

Comment: Tried that it just returned pretty much the same result for me.

Comment: sorry to hear that. I've been thinking of a workaround and maybe having an array of locations instead of only one could help. that way when you set a new one you do something like setLocations(prev => [...prev, newLocation]) and you do your logic with the last element in said array

Answer (score -1):

Maybe its would be helpful.

```js
const onClick = useCallback(({ location: { id, isActive, location } }) => {
  setActiveLocation((prevState: PreviousLocation) => {
    console.log("previousState", prevState);
    return new Map(prevState).set(id, isActive, location);
  });
}, []);
```